# Automate APK reverse engeeniring

Tags: java, android

I'm currently building a model to determine which permissions on Android applications represent the biggest threat to users.
For this purpose i have a total of 2gb of malicious Android applications apks which I need to decompress and get its manifest.xml.
I've investigated and found out that APK-tool lets me reverse engineer those files and get the file I want.
My question is, is there any way to automate this so I dont have to do the process manually for every apk file?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Usually "script" means a program written using scripting language. There's no additional magic here so if you know what you want to do, you know how to do, process can be automated then "yes". You can write a "script".